# Don't understand why I am getting this error on the else.

Tags: if-statement, recursion, methods, palindrome

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word, int firstIndex, int lastIndex)
{
    if(firstIndex>lastIndex)
        return true;    
    else if(word.charAt(firstIndex)==(word.charAt(lastIndex)));
    {
        return true && isPalindrome(word, firstIndex+1, lastIndex-1);   
    }
    **else**
        return false;

}
```

Getting error on else: "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token
"
I don't really get what is wrong with this code, specifically that else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi colon at the end of else if

```
else if(word.charAt(firstIndex)==(word.charAt(lastIndex)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String word, int firstIndex, int lastIndex)
{  
     boolean palindrome = false;
    if(firstIndex>lastIndex) {
          palindrome = true;   
     } 
    else if(word.charAt(firstIndex)==(word.charAt(lastIndex)))
    {
        if (isPalindrome(word, firstIndex+1, lastIndex-1)) {
           palindrome = true;
       }  
    }

      return palindrome;

}
```